# Java RegExp for a separated group of digits

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regexp validating:
one (or more) group of digits between 1 and 99 separated by `|` or `,` (both can be combined)

**Example**

Must accept:

```
1
10
1,2,3|5|10,20|30
1|5
```

Must refuse:

```
1,
10,,
1,2,3!5
```

For the group of digits, its straight forward: `[1-9][0-9]`.
For the rest, its a mystery (still).

**Question**

Can someone assist proposing the correct regexp ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^[1-9][0-9]?(?:[,|][1-9][0-9]?)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^            # Start of string
[1-9][0-9]?  # Match a number between 1 and 99
(?:          # Start of optional capturing group:
 [,|]        #  Match one separator
 [1-9][0-9]? #  and a number 1-99
)*           # any number of times (including 0)
$            # End of string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/FfvavR/1).

Comment: Opps. I tested a modified version to include 0: `^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])?(?:[,|][1-9][0-9]?)*$` . Sorry, its a different question now, but how can I include the difgit 0 (without empty value) ?

Comment: Raised a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359928/java-regexp-excluding-empty-values.

Answer (score 0):

```
\d([,|]?\d)*
```

is a possible candidate for your expressión, it means the repetition of at least one or more digits, separated (optionally ---the `?` after `[,|]` means optional) by any character from the set of { `','`, `'|'` }.

Proof:

- the interdigit separator is optional, so any number of digits can be between two separators.  This allows for sequences of digits of any length.
- there must be a maximum of one separator between digits (separator is optional, but must be followed by a digit).
- As the regexp begins with a digit, and forcedly ends in one, no acceptable `,` or `|` at the beginning or the end of the string.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bfBXNU/1/) to test it.

## Note

If you'd like to accept it on a line by line basis, rejecting things that begin or end with the separator chars, just anchor the regexp to beginning/end of the line with `^` and `$`.  As in [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/bfBXNU/2/).

```
^\d([,|]?\d)*$
```