# Java: regexp excluding empty values

Tags: java, regex

In the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359056/java-regexp-for-a-separated-group-of-digits), I got the regexp to match  one (or more) group of digits between 1 and 99 separated by | or , (both can be combined).

I want to update it to do the same, but accepting now digits between 0 and 99.

This modified version do that:

`^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])?(?:[,|][1-9][0-9]?)*$`  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359056/java-regexp-for-a-separated-group-of-digits)

But now accept empty values (see https://regex101.com/r/FfvavR/2)

**Question**

How can the regExp under [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359056/java-regexp-for-a-separated-group-of-digits) be modified to exclude empty value ?

Comment: Doesn't this work? ^[0-9][0-9]?(?:[,|][0-9][0-9]?)*$

Comment: [`^[1-9]?[0-9]+([,|][1-9]?[0-9])*$`](https://regex101.com/r/RTYopX/1)

Comment: No need for first grouping: `(?:<...>)` just it's content

Comment: You may use; [`^[0-9]{1,2}(?:[,|][0-9]{1,2})*$`](https://regex101.com/r/FfvavR/5)

Comment: @anubhava it will accept `00`

Comment: @alaster; That is still between 0 and 99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear if `00` is a valid or invalid entry. If `00` is allowed then use this regex:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}(?:[,|][0-9]{1,2})*$
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/FfvavR/5)

If `00` is not to be allowed then use this bit longish regex:

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])(?:[,|](?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?))*$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](http://%5E[0-9]%7B1,2%7D(?:[,%7C][0-9]%7B1,2%7D)*$)

Comment: That's work perfectly. Yes 00 is accepted, but its good to have the option to exclude it. In more, it accept `1,2,3,0,2` which is correct (others regexp won't match it). See it in action here:  https://regex101.com/r/CaizJE/1. Up voted, marked as correct thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Just remove first occurrence of `?:`. It makes group optional. So you have two optional groups that accepts empty string.

Also you can simplify `[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]` to `[1-9]?[0-9]` (`?` means first digit is optional)

Result:

```
^([1-9]?[0-9])(?:[,|][1-9]?[0-9])*$
```

Comment: Thanks, work almost. Up voted. Not marked answered as it refuse: `1,2,3,0,2` (see https://regex101.com/r/FfvavR/6)

Comment: Yeah, just copied op's regex. Second `[1-9][0-9]` must be replaced to `[1-9]?[0-9]` I'll update answer

Comment: @HeyStackExchange my mistake, fixed. now it works but refuses `00`

Comment: @alaster. That's correct. Anubhava has provide the solution with and without 00 before. So marked his answer as correct and up voted yours. Thanks !