# Java regexp: simplifying a reg exp

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm validating data.
For some fields, data can be expressed combining `|` and `,` char to separate a group of 1 or 2 digits.
The regexp doing that is expressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359928/java-regexp-excluding-empty-values).

For others fields, data can't mix both separators but must be one or the other.
So I modified the regexp [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359928/java-regexp-excluding-empty-values) to validate such field (see https://regex101.com/r/FfvavR/8)

```
^[0-9]{1,2}(?:[,][0-9]{1,2})*$|^[0-9]{1,2}(?:[|][0-9]{1,2})*$
```

It works perfectly:

It accept:

```
1
10
1|5
0
1,2,3,0,2
00
00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99
```

And it refuse:

```
1,
10,,
1,2,3!5
1|100
1,2,3|5|10,20|30
```

**Question**

I wonder if the new regexp could be simplified though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a regex for this, you may use

```
^[0-9]{1,2}(?=([,|])|$)(?:\1[0-9]{1,2})*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qheqAm/1)

Java:

```
String pat = "^[0-9]{1,2}(?=([,|])|$)(?:\\1[0-9]{1,2})*$";
```

If you are using it with `matches`, omit the leading `^` and trailing `$`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `(?=([,|])|$)` - a positive lookahead that captures into Group 1 a `,` or `|` char or matches the end of string (so as to allow `1`, `12`, etc.)
- `(?:\1[0-9]{1,2})*` - zero or more consecutive repetitions of

  - `\1` - Group 1 text (the first separator)
  - `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/wb4CTV):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("1","10","1|5","0","1,2,3,0,2","00","00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99","1,","10,,","1,2,3!5","1|100","1,2,3|5|10,20|30");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,2}(?=([,|])|$)(?:\\1[0-9]{1,2})*");
        for (String str : strs)
            System.out.println(str + ": \"" + p.matcher(str).matches() + "\"");
```

Output:

```
1: "true"
10: "true"
1|5: "true"
0: "true"
1,2,3,0,2: "true"
00: "true"
00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99: "true"
1,: "false"
10,,: "false"
1,2,3!5: "false"
1|100: "false"
1,2,3|5|10,20|30: "false"
```

Comment: I would suggest using a `java.util.regex.Pattern` because with that  `^` and `$` are never really used, when using `Pattern.matcher()` and then `Matcher.matches()` as you already said. When searching for multiple occurances one might just want to use `Matcher.find()`.

Comment: Work perfectly, well explained and complete answer thanks! https://regex101.com/r/qheqAm/2 Up voted and marked correct.

Comment: @Lino I mentioned that inside `matches` the first `^` and last `$` are not necessary. However, it is important not to leave out the `$` inside the lookahead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I saw that too late. I just wanted to mention that one could use `Pattern` for that which may be more performant than just calling `"SomeString".matches(pattern)` every time

Comment: @Lino OK, I added a Java demo.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified? Don't focus on the Regex only and use what Java offers you.

The more and more requirements and constraints you need to put on the Regex, the more likely you don't need one. Regex is good for the characters validation if matches the pattern correctly, not to validate against the exact range of numbers.

Since you have the valid format, parse the numbers from string to an array with `|` or `,` delimiter and validate. This is a correct, effective and straightforward way.

Regex is not the magic bullet for everything.

Comment: Thanks. Still, got to validate the data. And it sounds the best approach for my use case. Or you see a better one ?

Comment: Read the 3rd paragraph of my answer again. Use Regex only for the pattern validation to check whether the numbers are separated by `,` or `|`. For their range, don't use Regex anymore - it's an overkill.

Comment: In my use case, regexp are expressed in a DB (rule engine). The idea is to have the code agnostic from the real values. So its not applicable for me here.